# Trying to install Matplotlib on unix

Tags: matplotlib

I am just trying to install Matplotlib, and I used the command:

'$ pip install matplotlib'

and got this error:

error: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylab.py: Permission denied

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `sudo pip install matplotlib`

Comment: use virtual enviroments, don't use `sudo pip ...` as it can generate conflicts with system package installed files.